# как делать звонки/ видео звонки через Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Приветствую ! Кто нибудь знает как делать звонки/ видео звонки через Bluetooth ? Чтоб вопрос был более ясень приведу пример:
телефоны A и B связаны ( paired ) между собой, необходимо сделать звонок/видео звонок с телефона A на телефон B по каналу Bluetooth.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что для видеозвонков хватит пропускной способности блютуза на хоть сколько-нибудь приличное качество.

Comment: А что скажите насчет обычных звонков ?

Comment: Хватит. Существование гарнитур тому доказательство.

Comment: Вот мне нужны примеры кода или какие либо нормальные уроки по реализации данного функционала